# Mapping from passed props in a functional component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am building a website that is reliant on a json file for all of its information.
In my app.js the json info is showing properly when I console.log() it, but when I try and pass it to my functional components it is giving me undefined.

 in app.js

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/puppies"
  render={props => (
    <Puppies {...props} propdata={this.state.propdata} />
  )}
/>
```

This seems to be working fine, however when I try and map it inside the component it tells me that its undefined.

```
function Puppies(propdata) {
  return <div>{propdata.puppies.map(puppies => 
    <h1>{puppies.name}</h1>
  )}</div>;
}
```

I have done this before but with a class component. So most likely I am making a mistake with the functional component.
The full code is viewable here:
https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/Puppywebsite/tree/master/src

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you tell us the exact error you are getting?

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: So you're spreading in `props` and also passing an explicit prop called `propdata` into `Puppies`.  You then alias all your props to `propdata`.  Are you trying to access the specific prop called `propdata`?  If so, you'd either want to use dot notation `propdata.propdata` or to destructure it from your args `function Puppies({propdata}) {...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to check that the data is `null` of `undefined`. You are passing a big object with data, I recommend to pass more specific props instead of a big object.

I like to prevent my data to be `undefined` in 2 ways:

- [`lodash.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)
- [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Usage:

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

function Puppies({ propdata }) {
  const puppies = _.get(propdata, 'puppies', []);

  return (
    <div>
      {puppies.map(puppies => <h1>{puppies.name}</h1>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

or

```js
function Puppies({ propdata }) {
  const puppies = propdata?.puppies || [];

  return (
    <div>
      {puppies.map(puppies => <h1>{puppies.name}</h1>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the solution. Thanks for introducing me to lodash, I will be sure to use it in the future!

Answer (score 0):

What you have as `propdata` is actually just an object containing all properties that you have passed in. You should use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter) to get the actual `propdata` value.

Solution:

```
function Puppies({propdata}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {propdata.puppies.map(puppies => 
        <h1>{puppies.name}</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Trying this I am getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'puppies' of null" 
So I am guessing that there's something wrong with my propdata?

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp Sounds like it. To debug this you can `console.log` in the `Puppies` function right before returning.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is asynchronous request to get the data, your data is not readily available hence you need to handle that scenario.

```
function Puppies(propdata) {
return (
{
propdata.puppies.length>0 ? <div>

propdata.puppies.map((puppies)=>{
     <h1>{puppies.name}</h1>
})
</div> :null
 }
)
```

Comment: _"Since this is asynchronous request to get the data..."_ -- I don't see anything suggesting that in the original question; is this information you gleaned from looking at the source on Github?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is correct because  have had a similar issue before, however there is a syntax error i this answer that I just can't figure out in order to test it out.

Comment: Okay..let me rectify it.. Unfortunately I was on mobile..

Comment: check now and pls let me know